# Calculate number of days from date represented as integer

Tags: sql

I have a column (`EOM`) in my table(`Employee`) which gives the last day of the month as an integer and I want to return the number of days in the month. I know we can normally use the built-in functions but since the DATE that I have is stored as an int they won't work. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
EmpID    EmployeeName    EOM
123       ABC            20160731
345       XYZ            20150228
```

I want to know the number of days that say Employee ABC worked for which is 31.

Comment: (1) Edit your question and show sample data and desired results; (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as numbers and not a proper `DATE` column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right - we need to know what dbms you're using - a SQL Server answer will likely differ from a postgresql one. This applies to pretty much any SQL question.

Comment: IF `EOM` is an Integer representing the last day of the month,  `yyyymmdd`, you can simply extract the last two digits and get the number of days. This is a Modulo operation, in most DBMSes either `MOD(EOM,100)` or `EOM MOD 100`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the last day of the month in EOM column then you can simply take the last 2 characters from EOM column, which will give you number of days in the month.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(EOM,7,2) FROM EMPLOYEE
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(EOM,7,2)) FROM EMPLOYEE
```

This will give you the number which you can work with to get the number of days Employee worked for.